# Changing mutable property changes that property in every instance of the class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Looking at code below we see 2 instances of the same class. While we change a mutable property we actually change it to both instances. I find it tricky. Can anyone explain why does it act like this?

```
class MyClass:
    name: str = None
    dic: Dict[str, str] = {}


instance_1 = MyClass()
instance_2 = MyClass()
instance_1.name = ':)'
instance_1.dic['key'] = 'value'
print(instance_2.name)  # as expected prints None for immutable type str
print(instance_2.dic['key'])  # as unexpected prints value, for mutable type dic
```

Comment: Use `__init__` to give each class instance its own, private copy of the instance variables, particularly `dic`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to declare a dataclass but forgot the decorator. `@dataclass class MyClass: ...`.